# Output checks only 1st child in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have "ParentsOF" table where I have fields like generation. I would like to check if the person has lower money than average of his/her descendants. I can get only one level subordinate where I should check all descendants.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE rich_avg_descendant
as

CURSOR c IS select prior name pName, prior money pMoney, avg(money) average
                        FROM nikovits.parentof
                        START WITH name='ADAM'
                        CONNECT BY prior name = parent group by prior name,
                        prior money having prior money < avg(money);
BEGIN

    for i in c loop

        dbms_output.put_line(i.pName||' '||i.pMoney||' '||i.average);

    end loop;
END;
```

I am getting ( parent name, parent money, average money of descendant)

```
JOZSEF 150000 173500
PETER 143000 177000
SIMEON 154000 178500
GEDEON 120000 141000
```

But I should get

```
PETER 143000 177000
SIMEON 154000 178500
GEDEON 120000 141000
```

as average of descendants of JOSEPH is greater.

[image: Parents of table]

Comment: It would be great if you could add a create table statement and an insert statement. That makes it a lot easier for anyone to reproduce and solve your issue.

Comment: It would also be more helpful to show the actual query you ran to get the output (which would be better as formatted text, not an image), instead of PL/SQL code which may or may not be the same. At what point do you think the `avg` is calculated - particularly given that you have no `group by` or `over` clause?

Comment: Is the result actually any different in PL/SQL to what you get from SQL? I don't really see any PL/SQL-specific issues here.